# How to use UltiSnips in VIM for different PHP frameworks

Tags: php, laravel, vim, code-snippets

I have installed VIM, and VIM-Snippets, UltiSnips and YouCompleteMe.
UltiSnips offers different snippets files for php:

- php
- php-laravel
- php-phpspec
- php-symfony2

The `php` snippets work out of the box, and I can add php-laravel snippets with this command:

```
 :UltiSnipsAddFiletypes php-laravel
```

I want them as default for php files, so I tried this in my .vimrc:

```
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile,BufEnter *.php UltiSnipsAddFiletypes php-laravel
```

That does not work, so how do I add php-laravel snippets as default (in my .vimrc) for php files?

Comment: there is nothing wrong with your autocmd, probably the problem is with snippet paths. so add to your .vimrc file : `let g:UltiSnipsSnippetDirectories = ['UltiSnips']`

Comment: Create a file `php.snippets` in a private snippets directory, with contents `extends php-laravel, php`.  Read `:h UltiSnips-adding-snippets` and `:h g:UltiSnipsSnippetsDir` for details.

Comment: Thx, I followed [these instructions](https://github.com/honza/vim-snippets/blob/master/UltiSnips/php-phpspec.snippets), top two lines, but your suggestion does the trick. Could be answer, not comment.